# Taylor polynomial and formula for remainder

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let
$$ f(x) = (x+1)log(x+1), \text{$x\in]-1,\infty[$} $$
where log is the natural log.

a) Show that 
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^n(n-2)!}{(x+1)^{n-1}} \ \text{for $n\ge 2$ and $x\in]-1,\infty[ $}$$

The Taylor polynomial for $f$ of degree $3$ at the point $0$ is given by: 
$$(p_3f)(x) = x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3$$

b) Show that for $n\ge2$ and $x\ge0$ the remainder is given by the formula: 
$$ R_nf(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{(t+1)^n}dt $$

---

a) I know that the n'th derivative of $g(x) =log(x+1)$ is given by: 
$$g^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$$ 
So the n'th derivative of $f(x)$ is given by: 
$$f^{(n)} = (x+1)\cdot\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^{n-1}}$$

I am not quite sure how to go on from here with a)

b) I now that the Remainder can be expressed as: 
$$R_nf(x) = f(x) -T_n(x)$$ and $$R_nf(x) = \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x f^{(n+1)}(t)(x-t)^ndt $$
I know that I somehow have to use the second formula to show the desired in c), but I am not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: The $n^{th}$ derivative of $f = (x+1) \ln(x+1)$ _is not_ the same as the $n^{th}$ derivative of $g = \ln(x+1)$ times $(x+1)$. You need to apply the product rule to get the result \begin{align} f' &= 1 + \ln(x+1) \\ f'' &= \frac{1}{x+1} \\ f''' &= \frac{-1}{(x+1)^{3}} \\ f^{iv} &= \frac{2!}{(x+1)^{3}} \\ f^{v} &= \frac{-3!}{(x+1)^{4}} \\ &= \dots \\ \implies f^{n} &= \frac{(-1)^{n} (n-2)!}{(x+1)^{n-1}} \end{align}

Comment: In order to prove that it is the n'th derivative of $(x+1)ln(x+1)$ it has to be done with proof of induction or is there another way to make the argument?